# What is the range of $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know the domain is $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Is the range $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The output is a scalar, how could the range even be $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you raise $e$ to a power that is a real number, you always get a positive number.  So $0$ and negative numbers cannot be within the image of this function.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2+y^2\ge 0 \implies e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\le e^{-0}=1$$

$$x^2+y^2<\infty \implies e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\gt e^{-\infty}=0$$

So the range of $f(x,y)$ is $(0,1]$.

Comment: Note that this answer just proves that $\text{ran}(f)\subseteq ]0,1]$. You still need to prove the other inclusion.

Comment: I am not familiar with symbol $]0$. What does it mean?

Comment: The symbol $]$ is another way to denote $($.

Comment: If $0 < r \le 1$, $f(0, \sqrt{\ln(1/r)}) = r$.

Answer (score 2):

What are the possible values?  For example, $f(1,0)=e^{-1}$, so $e^{-1}$ is in the range.  Note $e^{-1}$ is not in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: So $[0, \infty)$? Since there is no way to get negative numbers

Comment: @RoyM. Can you get say, $e^2$? Can you get $0$?

Comment: Ah I see, no there is no way to get $e^2$ or $0$

Comment: @RoyM. Now what is special about $e^2$? What other numbers can't you get?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for all possible values of this function.

First note that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so the possible values of $f$ are real number.

Next notice that $x^2+y^2$ for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can reach all non-negative real value (choose real non-negative $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $x^2+y^2$ reach value $t$ for $(x,y)=(\sqrt{t},0)$ . Note that for $(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2$ $x^2+y^2$ don't reach negative value.

Now you can check range of $e^{-x^2-y^2}$:you know that range of $x^2+y^2$ (all non-negative real numbers), so $e^{-x^2-y^2}$ reach the same values like $e^{-t}$ for non-negative real $t$, so the range is $(0,1]$.